# What is a subset of a topological space?

Tags: general-topology

Apologies for the trivial question but it seems surprisingly hard to find a answer to this easily by Googling.

Generally when are we referring to a subset, $U$, of a topological space $(X,\mathcal{T})$, is $U$ a subset of $X$ or a subset of $\mathcal{T}$?

Also if relevant, why is it defined this way? Is there an easy way to remember which one?

Comment: $U$ is a subset of $X$. It is usual to refer to a topological space by the name of its underlying set, which in this case is $X$. The topology $\mathscr{T}$ is thought of as a kind of superstructure imposed on the set $X$.

Comment: I think your explanation is the clearest. Do you want to post this as an answer @BrianM.Scott ?

Comment: Thank you. Sure, I can do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$U$ is a subset of $X$. It is usual to refer to a topological space by the name of its underlying set, which in this case is $X$. The topology $\mathscr{T}$ is thought of as a kind of superstructure imposed on the set $X$.

Answer (score 1):

*U* as a subset of a topological space (*X*, *T*), is a subset of *X*, (so *U* $\subseteq$ *X*) ,that can gain a natural structure as a topological space (*U*, $T_U$) with $T_U$ := {O = U$\cap$A : A $\in$ *T* }

Answer (score 1):

When you say "Let $(X,\mathcal{T})$ be a topological space and a subset of this topological space $U$", it refers to a subset of $X$, BUT, this is because this subset has a natural topology induced by $\mathcal{T}$, if you take ${\displaystyle {\mathcal{T}_U}=\{S\cap U{\big |}S\in {\mathcal {T}}\}}$, you can prove that $\mathcal{T}_U$ is a topology of $U$, so you are actually refering to $(U,\mathcal{T}_U)$.